# How to use client side printer and scanner in ASP.Net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

using client side printer and scanner in ASP.Net c#

I m developing a web application in asp.net c# 4.0 ,
 It will be hosted on shared server hosting.
but i want to use client side printer. without out prompting print window to user.

Comment: what do you mean by client side printer? how do you know which printer to silently print?

Comment: Imagine a world in which any website you visit can access your printer without asking you.

Comment: The best you can do is generate a page of what you want to print, and tell the user to click a print button somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a web application to print without prompting to a user's clientside printer?

Not possible. This would be a big security flaw if browsers allowed that.